# Drawing angles on a graph

Tags: graphing-functions

Is there an easy way to draw lines on a graph to be at certain angles using only rise/run?
For example, to make a 45 degree angle with the x axis, the rise/run = 1.

Comment: if you have some "angle of inclination", $\theta$, then you may take the tangent ($\tan(\theta)$), and arrive at your slope $m$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a line of slope $m = {\text{rise}}/{\text{run}}$, and $\theta$ is the angle it makes with the x-axis, then $\tan(\theta) = m$.

This is because if you draw a right triangle from the angle, the rise/run ratio is the same as the side opposite of the angle divided by the adjacent side. This is the tangent function in trigonometry.

[image: triangle-angle-trig]

So you can use $\tan^{-1}(m)$, the *inverse tangent* function (sometimes written as the "$\text{arctangent}$", or "$\arctan(m)$"), to find the measure of the angle $\theta$.

Most scientific calculators will have an inverse tangent function. Microsoft Excel also has an `ATAN(number)` function, though it gives the resulting angle in radians. You have to convert it to degrees by entering `=+DEGREES(ATAN(1))` for example to get back 45.

Answer (score 1):

The slope (rise/run) of a line which forms an angle $\theta$ with the positive x-axis is $\tan \theta$, which you can calculate using a scientific calculator or a website of your choice. Unfortunately, for most angles this is not a nice number.